How to create a combination of table and chart for a report document
I'm currently developing a report document of the personality test. I did some benchmark. A lot of professional tests have a quite good (e.g. not too sophisticated, but not cheap) design.
Here's some samples:
1. Sample report of Strong Interest Inventory

In this image, the bar that passes columns confuses me on how to do it.
2. Sample report from Career Assessment Inventory

This second image also done similar thing, passing bar to the columns.
Question
Since i'm new in creating this report, here i have few questions and need guidance:

What is the recommended resources to learn to make this kind of report document.
What principles do I need to understand to start learning to create this graphic/table in the report?

During my research, I stumbled upon this thread on creating chart inside table, but to the best of my knowledge, those bars can't bypass the columns.
Note: Also, if you have the sample code, it might helps me learn a lot.

Welcome. There are ways to have the bar bypass the columns (by using overlay or by simply not using real columns in the first place). Input syntax and what kind of tabular you need are more important to be able to choose the way forwards.

why do you think the images were created using tex, as you question seems to imply?

@Qrrbrbirlbel thanks. Okay so the logic is to make table first like using \begin{tabular}. And then creating chart inside the cell. The first image as an example, its consists of 3 columns, first col has 4 rows (exclude header), second col has 1 row, and third col has 4 rows again. In that 1 row of second column where I put my created chart. The number 30, 40, 50, etc., and their vertical line is part of the chart. Is this logic works?

@cfr oh actually, I don't know what program they use to generate their report. Sorry for unintentionally implying that. I'm asking in Tex forum because I'm started to learn that and wondering if posted images possible to create in Tex

I find that table-chart-mix visually confusing. Suggestion to find a cleaner way of conveying the message.
